# JQuery: Fancybox is not working inside Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins, fancybox

Inside a Google Map i have to give the possibility to expand the images.
Fancybox is the exact solution i need, but unfortunately for some reasons is not working.

http://jsbin.com/ISeZUPaY/2

In this example you can see how fancybox is working properly outside the map but is not working inside it.

Do you know why this is happening?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

I have tried using the Infowindow instead of the Infobox, and so far is working fine:

http://jsbin.com/evIjuFO/2

So the problem is not about incompatibility between Google map and Fancybox, as i supposed, but between the infobox of google map and Fancybox.
So now the question is: How can i make working Fancybox inside the infobox?

Thank you.

Comment: What I see is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' `

Comment: @Dr.Molle It's because your call to fancybox js file returns `403 Forbidden` ... you need to load the file in another window so it can be cached http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js

Comment: @JFK: This was only a comment to *In this example you can see how fancybox is working properly* ...because nothing works there.

Comment: @Dr.Molle : it does though (at least the fancybox image under the map)

Comment: What is not working exactly?
Do you see the map and the image under it?

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
enableEventPropagation: true
```

in your infobox options